# Memory Allocation of Static String Literals

Tags: c

Consider the following struct:

```
struct example_t {
char * a;
char * b;
};

struct example_t test {
"Chocolate",
"Cookies"
};
```

I am aware of the implementation specific nature of the allocation of memory for the char*'s, but what of the string literals?

**In this case, are there any guarantee from the C-standard with regards to the adjacent placement of "Chocolate" and "Cookies"?**

In most implementations I tested the two literals are not padded, and are directly adjacent.

This allows the struct to be copied quickly with a memcpy, although I suspect this behavior is undefined.  Does anyone have any information on this topic?

Comment: The struct consists of two pointers (which will most likely be adjacent). This has nothing to do at all with the pointers' values.

Comment: It is of no consequence if the two string are in adjacent memory. `memcpy` would not copy them - only the pointers.

Comment: Obviously, although your comment may be useful to others who may not realize this.  The memcpy I mention would be executed at the location of the first pointer.

Comment: Before trying to use `memcpy` to "copy quickly", please read [memcpy vs assignment in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324011/memcpy-vs-assignment-in-c)

Comment: @BoPersson **excellent point.**  Moral: Don't prefer memcpy vs assignment for performance, _but_ it may be convenient to do so.  (I.e. if this struct had 4+ strings, it may be programmically more simple to write one line of code, vs a loop.)

Comment: @DonScott - But you don't need a loop, or several lines, you can just assign one struct to another, and let the compiler figure out how to do that.

Comment: @BoPersson The strings are not const, so a deep copy is required as the copy likely can change the values.  Assignment would only copy the pointers, not copy the underlying strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, there are no **absolute** guarantees of the adjacency/placement of the two string literals with respect to each other. GCC in this case happens to demonstrate such behavior, but it has no obligation to exhibit this behavior.

In this example, we see no padding, and we can even use undefined behavior to demonstrate adjacency of string literals. This works with GCC, but using alternate `libc`'s or different compilers, you could get other behavior, such as detecting duplicate string literals across translation units and reducing redundancy to save memory in the final application.

Also, while the pointers you declared are of type `char *`, the literals actually should be `const char*`, since they will be stored in `RODATA`, and writing to that memory will cause a segfault.

---

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct example_t {
char * a;
char * b;
char * c;
};


int main(void) {

    struct example_t test = {
        "Chocolate",
        "Cookies",
        "And milk"
    };
    size_t len = strlen(test.a) + strlen(test.b) + strlen(test.c) + ((3-1) * sizeof(char));

    char* t= test.a;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        printf("%c", t[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Sample output**

---

```
./a.out 
ChocolateCookiesAnd milk
```

---

**Output of gcc -S**

---

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Chocolate"
.LC1:
    .string "Cookies"
.LC2:
    .string "And milk"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $72, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    movq    $.LC0, -48(%rbp)
    movq    $.LC1, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $.LC2, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strlen
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strlen
    addq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strlen
    addq    %rbx, %rax
    addq    $2, %rax
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -56(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -68(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movl    -68(%rbp), %eax
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    movq    -56(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    movzbl  (%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    putchar
    addl    $1, -68(%rbp)
.L2:
    movl    -68(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    cmpq    -64(%rbp), %rax
    jb  .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $72, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no guarantee for adjacent placement.

One occasion where actual compilers will place them far apart is if the same string literal appears in different places (as read-only objects) and the *string combining* optimization is enabled.

Example:

```
 char *foo = "foo";
 char *baz = "baz";
 struct example_t bar = {
     "foo",
     "bar"
 }
```

may well end up in memory as `"foo"` followed by `"baz"` followed by `"bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example demonstrating a real-world scenario where the strings are not adjacent.  GCC decides to reuse the string `"Chocolate"` from earlier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *a = "Chocolate";
const char *b = "Spinach";

struct test_t {
    const char *a;
    const char *b;
};

struct test_t test = {"Chocolate", "Cookies"};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%p %p\n", (const void *) a, (const void *) b);
    printf("%p %p\n", (const void *) test.a, (const void *) test.b);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
0x400614 0x40061e
0x400614 0x400626
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to show you an example of gcc behaviour where, even in that case you don't get strings aligned in memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *s = "Cookies";

struct test {
    char *a, *b, *c, *d;
};

struct test t = {
    "Chocolate",
    "Cookies",
    "Milk",
    "Cookies",
};

#define D(x) __FILE__":%d:%s: " x, __LINE__, __func__

#define P(x) do{\
    printf(D(#x " = [%#p] \"%s\"\n"), x, x); \
} while(0)

int main()
{
    P(t.a);
    P(t.b);
    P(t.c);
    P(t.d);
    return 0;
}
```

In this  case, as the compiler tries to reuse already seen string literals, the ones you use to assign to the structure fields don't get aligned.

This is the output of the program:

```
$ pru3
pru3.c:25:main: t.a = [0x8518] "Chocolate"
pru3.c:26:main: t.b = [0x8510] "Cookies"
pru3.c:27:main: t.c = [0x8524] "Milk"
pru3.c:28:main: t.d = [0x8510] "Cookies"
```

As you see, the pointers are even repeated for the `"Cookies"` value.

The compiling here was made with default values, with:

```
gcc -o pru3 pru3.c
```